# Only seeing results from last .each() iteration in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to iterate through some stuff in a JSON file and I'm having trouble getting the each() to do what I want. Here's what I have:

```
$.each(response.data.items, function(i,data)
{
var id=data.id; 
var results="<div><iframe width='320' height = '190' src='http://www.example.com/"+id+"' frameborder='0' type='text/html'></iframe></div>";

$("#resultsOut").html(results);
});
```

Right now, the only HTML that is being output is

```
<div><iframe width='320' height = '190' src='http://www.example.com/"+id+"' frameborder='0' type='text/html'></iframe></div>
```

where id is the last id that occurs in the JSON. How do I change this so that instead I see that HTML block once for every id that occurs?

Comment: Have you double-checked the JSON data to make sure you have multiple results?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to

```
$(results).appendTo("#resultsOut");
```

instead of

```
$("#resultsOut").html(results)
```

because `.html()` *replaces* the contents of the selected element with the new HTML, rather than adding to it.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the inner HTML of `$("#resultsOut")` every time. Do something like this:

```
$.each(response.data.items, function(i,data)
{
    var id=data.id; 
    var results="<div><iframe width='320' height = '190' src='http://www.example.com/"+id+"'      frameborder='0' type='text/html'></iframe></div>";

    $("#resultsOut").append($(results));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only seeing the last id because you are overwriting the previous HTML with every iteration. Try using .append():

```
$.each(response.data.items, function(i,data)
{
var id=data.id; 
var results="<div><iframe width='320' height = '190' src='http://www.example.com/"+id+"' frameborder='0' type='text/html'></iframe></div>";

$("#resultsOut").append(results);
});
```